# Eloquent query with COALESCE, IF, complex ON clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

i'd like to ask, how would you write the following query in Laravel Eloquent?

Please note the `COALESCE`, `IF`, and the complex `LEFT JOIN ... ON (... AND ...)`.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(IF(customer_group_id=6, prices.price, NULL), products.price) AS finalPrice, prices.customer_group_id, products.*, product_translations.*
FROM `product_categories`
    LEFT JOIN `products` ON `product_categories`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `product_translations` ON `product_translations`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `prices` 
        ON (`products`.`id` = `prices`.`product_id` AND `prices`.`customer_group_id` = 6 )
WHERE `product_translations`.`locale` = 'it'
    AND `products`.`online` = 1
    AND `products`.`sellable` = 1
    AND `category_id` = 22
```

---

UPDATE: By far, what i came up with is the following:

```php
ProductCategory::leftjoin('products', 'product_categories.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                    ->leftJoin('product_translations', 'product_translations.product_id', 'products.id')
                    ->leftJoin('prices', function($join) use($customer_group_id) {
                        $join->on('products.id', '=', 'prices.product_id')
                             ->on('prices.customer_group_id', '=', DB::raw($customer_group_id));
                      })
                    ->select(
                        DB::raw('coalesce(if(customer_group_id='.$customer_group_id.',prices.price,NULL), products.price) AS finalPrice'),
                        'prices.customer_group_id',
                        'products.*',
                        'product_translations.*'
                    )
                    ->where('product_translations.locale', '=', $locale)
                    ->where('products.online', '=', true)
                    ->where('products.sellable', '=', true)
                    ->where('category_id', '=', $this->id);
```

Comment: What is the output of your code vs the output of your SQL? Please clarify what is not working here. Also, there's a `->toSql()` method you can call to generate the SQL for comparison.

Comment: @TimLewis the output of the code i came up with is the same as the sql query, i'm asking if there's some way to improve my code, making it more readable or syntactically correct. I'm not sure about the DB::raw statements in particular

Comment: So it's already working correctly then? If the syntax wasn't correct it wouldn't execute at all. As for readability, that's a matter of opinion

Comment: Ah, gotcha! To be honest, I think what you've got is good! There isn't a `->coalesce()` method in Laravel (amongst others), so some statements need to use that `DB::raw()` syntax. You could try posting over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, see if they have any suggestions on improvement, but if your code is working, it's probably not the best fit for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 10 now supports database expressions with grammar-specific formatting, which makes it possible to write DB engine agnostic ORM queries (without DB::raw-ing everything):
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/44784

```
class Alias implements Expression
{
    public function __construct(
    public readonly Expression|string $expression,
    public readonly string $name,
    ) { }

    public function getValue(Grammar $grammar): string
    {
        return match ($grammar->isExpression($this->expression)) {
            true => "{$grammar->getValue($this->expression)} as {$grammar->wrap($this->name)}",
            false => $grammar->wrap("{$this->name} as {$this->name}"),
        };
    }
}

class Coalesce implements Expression
{
    public function __construct(
        public readonly array $expressions,
    ) { }

    public function getValue(Grammar $grammar): string
    {
        $expressions = array_map(function ($expression) use($grammar): string {
            return match ($grammar->isExpression($expression)) {
                true => $grammar->getValue($expression),
                false => $grammar->wrap($expression),
            };
        }, $this->expressions);
        $expressions = implode(', ', $expressions);

        return "coalesce({$expressions})";
    }
}
```

using this you can now:

```
    DB::table('table')
    ->select(new Alias(new Coalesce(['user', 'admin']), 'count'));
```

Comment: ...and from the future comes exactly what i was looking for. Bye bye `DB::raw`. Thanks!